# How to pass an HttpResponse and additional data via Ajax in Django

Tags: python, json, ajax, django, django-views

I have two different AJAX requests that I want to combine.

The first one gets some html:

```
def ajax_get_html(request):
    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == "POST":
        context = {
            ...
        }
        return render(request,"my_app/my_template.html", context)
    else:
        raise Http404
```

And is used like this:

```
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: ajax_url,
      data: {
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}",
      },
      success: function(data){
        $(my_div).html(data);
      }
    });
```

My second one gets some data:

```
def ajax_get_data(request):
    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == "POST":
        data = {
            "answer": 42,
        }
        json_data = json.dumps(data)
        return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type='application/json')
    else:
        raise Http404
```

and is used like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: another_ajax_url,
    data: {
      csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}",
    },
    success: function(data){
      var answer = data.answer;
      $("#notification_badge").html(answer);
    }
  });
```

How can I combine these to into the same request?  I tried adding the result of `render` to the data in the second view, but json.dumps says it's non serializable.

Comment: Take a look over this -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects

Comment: I had read through that, but I'm too much of a noob to understand it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't serialize the output of Django's `render` because it [returns an HttpResponse object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/#render), not a string (which is what you want to be able to serialize it).

A good solution is to return your html to the frontend using [`render_to_string`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string):

```
...
data = {
    "answer": 42,
    "html": render_to_string("my_app/my_template.html", context)
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks! I just had to add the request to render_to_string and it worked.